# Create new data.frame based on binary (0/1) data.frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data.frames (df1 and binary df2) and I want to create a third data.frame (df3) based on df1 conditioned on the binary data.frame df2. I want to set all values to zero if there is a zero at that position in the binary data.frame 2.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    '01K W':[1.2, 2.3, 0.3, 0.5], 
    '02K W':[3.5, 0.1, 'nan', 'nan'], 
    '03K W':[4.2, 5.2, 2.5, 3.0], 
    '04K W':[1.5, 2.6, 8.2, 4.2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    '01K W':[1, 1, 1, 1], 
    '02K W':[1, 0, 0, 0], 
    '03K W':[0, 0, 0, 1], 
    '04K W':[0, 1, 1, 0]})
```

To create the new data.frame 3, I was thinking about a for loop over the columns and replacing the values in df1 based on df2 (values=0). So far, I wasn't able to figure out a correct syntax.

```
df3 = for col in df1.columns:
    if df2[col].value[1:] == 0:
        df3[col].value[1:] = 0
    else:
        df3[col].value[1:] = df1[col].value
```

I would expect a data.frame which looks like that:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    '01K W':[1.2, 2.3, 0.3, 0.5], 
    '02K W':[3.5, 0, 0, 0], 
    '03K W':[0, 0, 0, 3.0], 
    '04K W':[0, 2.6, 8.2, 0]})
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Are the values of the DataFrame strings?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, no actually the values are numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index df1 by df2. Since df2 is of string dtype, first convert to boolean.

```
df2_bool = df2.set_index('Date').astype(int).astype(bool)

df1.set_index('Date')[df2_bool].fillna(0).reset_index()
```

You get

```
    Date        01K W   02K W   03K W   04K W
0   2021-01-01  1.2     3.5     0       0
1   2021-01-02  2.3     0       0       2.6
2   2021-01-03  0.3     0       0       8.2
3   2021-01-04  0.5     0       3.0     0
```

Ofcourse you can make it a one-line (and avoid saving boolean df2)

```
df1.set_index('Date')[df2.set_index('Date').astype(int).astype(bool)].fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
bm = df2.sort_values('Date').set_index('Date').astype(int).astype(bool).values

df1.sort_values('Date').set_index('Date').where(bm, 0).reset_index()
```

Basically you create a binary matrix:

```
df2.sort_values('Date').set_index('Date').astype(int).astype(bool).values
```

Then you use the pandas where clause.

NOTE: This will only work if all dates are in `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes in my case the dates match.

Answer (score 1):

This code below will work.

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Date').astype(float)
df2 = df2.set_index('Date').astype(float)
df1.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df3 = df1 * df2
```

You can use fillna() if df2 also has null values.

The operation is a simple matrix multiplication.

you can also do this.

```
df1.mul(df2)
```

Comment: Nice thanks a lot, I wasn't thinking about such an intuitive solution :)

Comment: Thanks, You might consider verifying this solution :)